# how to validate multiple different data from postman response

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, postman, response

I have created test scripts by considering response as given below,

```
{ "page": 2,
   "per_page": 6, 
   "total": 12,  
   "total_pages": 2, 
   "data": [       
             {"id": 7, 
              "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
              "first_name": "Michael", 
              "last_name": "Law}]}
```

I used script ( **pm.jsondata.data[1].id**)and it is working fine for above response,but it is not working for response given below

```
 [

    {
        "userId": 6275,
        "userName": "samual",
        "accountId": 54751,
        
    },
    {
        "userId": 8126,
        "userName": "Martine",
        "accountId": 54751,
        
    }]
```

I used **jsondata=pm.response.json;
jsondata[1].userId**

but I getting error like  **TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

```
 jsondata=pm.response.json()
 jsondata[1].userId
```

json is a method you have to call json() not json

Answer (score 0):

You need to access that using,

```
jsondata.data[1].userId
```

As from your prev response it is clear that the array is inside the key `data`.

If that doesn't work, you need to console log your `jsondata` variable and see where the array is.

Comment: thanks but getting same error since in 2nd response there is no data variable available.

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {…}
userId: 6275
userName: "sam"